# How do we record our game and upload it to youtube in clash of clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

These guy can do it.

https://www.3starsclanwars.com/tag/ucla-affiliates-defeats-vip-team%E8%A1%80%E6%88%B0%E5%88%B0%E5%BA%95

How do they do that?

I am using IOS and iPhone.

Comment: What OS and OS version are you running it on? You should add that to the question.

Answer (score 6):

[If you have a Mac](http://www.howtogeek.com/199732/how-to-record-a-video-of-your-iphone-or-ipad%E2%80%99s-screen-from-your-mac/):

- Connect Your iPhone or iPad to Your Mac
- Launch QuickTime
- Click the File menu on the top of your screen and select “New Movie
  Recording.”
- Click the arrow next to the red Record button and select your iPad or
  iPhone.
- Record your video and play it back
- To save it, click the File > Save menu option and choose a file name
  and location.

If you don't, you will need to get a Digital AV adapter compatible with your phone and plug it into a computer with capture software installed.